# Google analytics: tracking not working in subdomain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

I have a website which has multiple subdomains. GA code is implemented in both root & subdomain1. While the root GA tracking is working perfectly, no counts are registered in the subdomain1.root.com. Both use the same tracking id.

**Below is the code for root.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-TRACKINGCODE-1', 'root.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

**Tracking code for the subdomain1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
    m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
    ga('create', 'UA-TRACKINGCODE-1', 'root.com');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
```

I see the website address in the subdomain code is pointing to the root address. Is this a cause of concern? Or what am I missing?

Comment: To, that is not a point of concern. That is the cookie domain. Setting the root domain simply means that the same cookie is used for  subdomains and base domain, which seems to be what you are after (if you want to track all subdomains you might as well set "auto" instead of the domain name).

Comment: Thanks @EikePierstorff. Sorry for being naive, but setting it 'auto' will solve the issue?

Comment: @EikePierstorff I did change the 'root.com' to 'auto' in the subdomain code but still tracking isn't working. What else could be the issue?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I was trying to say that this probably not your problem ("auto" is just simpler than typing put the domain). If you're on Chrome you can install the Google Analytics debugger extension which will print helpful error messages to the browser console in the developer tools. Your code looks alright, so it's not really possible to save the problem with the info from your post.

Answer (score -2):

I found this link for tracking subdomains with a Root domain, but I don't know where to implement the code: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#domainSubDomains

Code they say to use:
    
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker('UA-12345-1');
    pageTracker._setDomainName('example-petstore.com');
    pageTracker._trackPageview();

Comment: Nope, that's outdated syntax and not supported by the version of the Analytics code the OP is using.

Comment: Then, why is it on Google's developer web site?